# Submit form with route variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm creating search form in laravel.

After form submit I want to get /search/{search_phrase} URL, i.e /search/cats

How do I create such URL in controler or by submitting form ?

I've tried for now (in controller) `return view('search.index', ['search' => $search]);` but this didn't worked.

I know I can pass variable this way: `{{ Form::open(['action' => 'VentureController@searchByField', $search]) }}` but this would be predefined variable and it is not working in this situation.

Comment: You'll have to either use javascript for that, or submit to a page which reads the form input value and redirects to a custom route. There's nothing built-in that can do this, since html doesn't work that way. Your other option would be using a get form rather than a post one.

Comment: If you open a form you may submit a form input field. I share an [example](https://github.com/timegridio/timegrid/blob/master/resources/views/manager/_navmenu.blade.php#L30) of how im doing for my project.